# Foreach MVC3 MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net, c, asp.net-mvc-3, foreach

i have implemented a class inherits TableServiceEntity that adds a few propertys called UserEntity.

In a view, i want to do a foreach loop to show all the entries like this:

```
@model MembershipUserCollection
```

If i do

```
   @foreach (UserEntity user in Model) {

     <td>

        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.ID_client)
    </td>
     <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => user.Username)
    </td>
....
....


}
```

VS2010 tells me that cant convert an object type from 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser' to 'AzureTableStorage.UserEntity'.

And if i change the model

```
@model UserEntity
```

The shows me another error..

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'UserEntity' because 'UserEntity' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

And the UserEntity class have the properties declared like this..

```
   public class UserEntity : TableServiceEntity
   {

    public UserEntity(string partitionKey, string rowKey) : base(partitionKey, rowKey)
    {
    }

    public UserEntity() : this(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), String.Empty)
    {
    }


    public int ID_client { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
    public String Password { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
```

..........
.......
......

(Where Username and some more properties are the same from MembershipUser.. but not alls, i have added 3 or 4 extra).

Can someone helps me?

Thanks.

Comment: Those error messages say it all

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing won't work.  The error messages are telling you that.

This is the problem with all this wizard generated code, is that you don't understand how it works.  And therefore, when something breaks, you don't know how to fix it.  I suggest you understand why you are getting the errors you are getting.  There are reasons for them.  If you understand the reasons, the solution will be more obvious.

Comment: Ok Mystere. I will try again a few hours, dont worry. But i wrote it if there some strange error because i have spent a lot of hours on my project, and this i cant fix it.

In the first case, can i convert one object directly to another type?

Thanks.